# i'm unable to get object data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Facebook login` with `Socialite` which is `dumping` the user as shown below.

```
 dd($user);
```

**output:**

[image]

How to get `user` details from above `object` shown in image?

i'm trying to access like this but getting `error`

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

dd($user->user[0],$user->user[1],$user->user[2],$user->user[3],$user->user[4]);
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: undefined index

Comment: `undefined index` means that the index you are accessing does not exist in your case I think it is `$user->             >>>>>>user<<<<<< [0]` Try `var_dump($user);` and you will see what indexes the `$user` has

Comment: Please check with this `echo "<pre>";print_r($user['user']);die;` OR `echo "<pre>";print_r($user->user);die;`

Comment: How about `dd($user->user)`?

Comment: @Alfa,  i'm getting `array:5 [▼
  "name" => "Ejaz Anwar"
  "gender" => "male"
  "verified" => true
  "link" => "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1549063411868161/"
  "id" => "1549063411868161"
]`

Comment: Is that what you want? You get `user` from that object. If that is not what you want, then what kind of `user` detail you want to get?

Comment: How about: `dd(Socialite::driver('github')->userFromToken($user->token))`?

Comment: if possible to achieve this answer with `array_map()` then please provide your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this to get the user data array from the socialite result

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
$user=json_decode(json_encode($providerUser,true),true);
$user=$user['user'];
```

Comment: i'm very easily getting these parameter but right now i'm intestred is `user` details   `+user: array:5 [▼
    "name" => "Ejaz Anwar"
    "gender" => "male"
    "verified" => true
    "link" => "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1549063411868161/"
    "id" => "1549063411868161"
  ]`

Comment: my whole object looks like this `User {#230 ▼
  +refreshToken: null
  +expiresIn: 5180774
  +id: "1549063411868161"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "Ejaz Anwar"
  +email: null
  +avatar: "https:type=normal"
  +user: array:5 [▼
    "name" => "Ejaz Anwar"
    "gender" => "male"
    "verified" => true
    "link" => "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1549063411868161/"
    "id" => "1549063411868161"
  ]
  +"avatar_original": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/1549063411868161/picture?width=1920"
  +"profileUrl": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1549063411868161/"
}`

Comment: with your answer i'm able to get `user` `array` seperately  that helped me